# Python read file as stream from HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, subprocess, hdfs

Here is my problem: I have a file in HDFS which can potentially be huge (=not enough to fit all in memory)

What I would like to do is avoid having to cache this file in memory, and only process it line by line like I would do with a regular file:

```
for line in open("myfile", "r"):
    # do some processing
```

I am looking to see if there is an easy way to get this done right without using external libraries. I can probably make it work with [libpyhdfs](http://code.google.com/p/libpyhdfs/) or [python-hdfs](https://github.com/traviscrawford/python-hdfs) but I'd like if possible to avoid introducing new dependencies and untested libs in the system, especially since both of these don't seem heavily maintained and state that they shouldn't be used in production.

I was thinking to do this using the standard "hadoop" command line tools using the Python `subprocess` module, but I can't seem to be able to do what I need since there is no command line tools that would do my processing and I would like to execute a Python function for every linein a streaming fashion.

Is there a way to apply Python functions as right operands of the pipes using the subprocess module? Or even better, open it like a file as a generator so I could process each line easily?

```
cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/path/to/myfile"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If there is another way to achieve what I described above without using  an external library, I'm also pretty open.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You could use https://bitbucket.org/turnaev/cyhdfs i released it few days ago and it is used in production. PyPI link http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cyhdfs/0.1.2 is slightly older bu ok.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You want [xreadlines](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-xreadlines.html), it reads lines from a file without loading the whole file into memory.

**Edit**:

Now I see your question, you just need to get the stdout pipe from your `Popen` object:

```
cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/path/to/myfile"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cat.stdout:
    print line
```

Comment: How is this different from doing a `for line in open("myfile")`? I think the difficulty here is that I'm not dealing with a regular file, but a file that is in HDFS and I'm wondering if there's a way I can make the subprocess module (or something else) process it line by line with some Python code. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question then.  Don't you want to process it line by line *in python*?  Doesn't HDFS have a way to `cat` a file?  (I hope it does.)  Just call that as a subprocess and wrap the result in an `xreadlines` or a `for line in...`.

Comment: Yes you can cat a file with `hadoop fs -cat /path/to/myfile`, as I've written in the little subprocess statement above. Maybe I'm missing something, but objects returned by `subprocess.Popen` are not iterable file-like objects, right? I've tried doing a `for line in ...` on my `cat` object above but all I get is `TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable`. Am I misunderstanding something? It would be awesome if you could show a little example of what you're thinking of.

Comment: That works great, I had no idea the `stdout` and `stderr` of a `Popen` object could be used like files, easier than I thought, thanks for the help !

Comment: Note that if you replace -cat with -text it will handle compression too.

Comment: Note that, since 2.3, [`xreadlines` is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-xreadlines.html) (just use `for line in file`, as in your **Edit**).

Comment: @CharlesMenguy: On Python 2, you could use `for line in iter(cat.stdout.readline, ''): print line,` (note: comma at the end): it fixes two issues with the answer: 1. there is a read-ahead bug in Python 2 that delays output from the `cat` command 2. `print line` (no comma) may introduce unnecessary newlines

Comment: Instead of forking a separate process to call `hadoop fs -cat`, it may be preferrable to specify an HDFS path in the `-files` argument when you run the application.  This tells YARN to pull the file as a local resource to the nodes running the containers.  The Python code can then load it as a local file in the working directory.  This technique can provide better performance in very large jobs.  More details are in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362331/mapreduce-how-to-allow-mapper-to-read-an-xml-file-for-lookup/34366077#34366077

Answer (score 32):

If you want to avoid adding external dependencies at any cost, Keith's answer is the way to go.  [Pydoop](http://pydoop.sourceforge.net), on the other hand, could make your life much easier:

```py
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
with hdfs.open('/user/myuser/filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something(line)
```

Regarding your concerns, Pydoop is actively developed and has been used in production for years at [CRS4](http://www.crs4.it), mostly for computational biology applications.

Simone

Comment: [hdfscli](http://hdfscli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) have similar functionalities, and it's more lightweight. Don't forget to enable WebHDFS to use it.

Comment: @simleo I get an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute open

Comment: @JohnConstantine if you're having problems with Pydoop you should open an issue at https://github.com/crs4/pydoop/issues

Answer (score 1):

In the last two years, there has been a lot of motion on Hadoop-Streaming.  This is pretty fast according to Cloudera: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/  I've had good success with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WebHDFS Python Library (built on top of urllib3):

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client_hdfs = InsecureClient('http://host:port', user='root')
with client_hdfs.write(access_path) as writer:
    dump(records, writer)  # tested for pickle and json (doesnt work for joblib)
```

Or you can use the requests package in python as:

```
import requests
from json import dumps
params = (('op', 'CREATE')
('buffersize', 256))
data = dumps(file)  # some file or object - also tested for pickle library
response = requests.put('http://host:port/path', params=params, data=data)  # response 200 = successful
```

Hope this helps!