# How to read file stored in hdfs using python Open() method?

Tags: python, hadoop-streaming

I would like read a file from HDFS using Python `open()` method . However it is not working. Can someone give me a method to read hdfs file using Open() method in python.

```
for line in open("hdfs://namenode:54311/user/hadoop/filename.txt"):
```

However it gives me an error

> "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'hdfs://namenode:54311/user/hadoop/filename.txt'"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python read file as stream from HDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485718/python-read-file-as-stream-from-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

The built in [`open` doesn't work with URIs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). E.g. It would also error out on `open("http://example.com/index.html")`.

Your question is well answered in the suggested duplicate.