# Can we integrate Hadoop with Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have one project requirement. I'm using python script for analyzing the data. Initially, I used the txt files as an input to that python script. But as data grows, I have to switch my storage platform to Hadoop HDFS. How can I provide HDFS data to python script as an input? Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Hadoop streaming for using python,php etc Ex: hadoop jar hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.2.jar -mapper /mapper.php -reducer /reducer.php -input /hdfsinputpath -output /hdfsoutputpath

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485718/python-read-file-as-stream-from-hdfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop Streaming API:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-input myInputDirs \
-output myOutputDir \
-mapper /bin/cat \
-reducer /bin/wc
```

All you need to know about that is here:
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: This is what I am looking for. So, basically everything will be handled by Hadoop-streaming.jar right? No need for extra work.. am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other approaches, you can also embed Pig Latin statements and Pig commands in Python script using a JDBC-like compile, bind, run model. For Python, make sure the Jython jar is included in your class path. Refer apache pig documentation here for more details: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#embed-python