# Parse HDFS Files from Pycharm

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am running a parser file to parse files from .txt files from a local directory. Now these files are moved to HDFS cluster and I would like to configure my Pycharm to access the HDFS cluster. Can someone assist me in doing this?

Comment: What Python Hadoop library are you using? You will need one to access those files as `open()` will not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read file as stream from HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485718/python-read-file-as-stream-from-hdfs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to configure my Pycharm to access the HDFS cluster

Depends on what type of *access* you're referring to. As far as the HDFS CLI basics, you can do that with `os`

```
# Not tested
import os 
import sys 

f = "{}/tmp.txt".format(os.getcwd())
cmds = [
    "touch {}".format(f),
    "hadoop fs -copyFromLocal {} /user/$USER/".format(f),
    "rm -fv {}".format(f),
    "hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/$USER/tmp.txt $PWD/",
]
for cmd in cmds:
    os.system(cmd)
assert os.path.exists(f)
```

But if you're looking for more granular control you'll want something like [pyarrow](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/) (or the like)

Comment: Won't the assert fail because you removed the file?

Comment: No because we copy the file back with `"hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/$USER/tmp.txt $PWD/"`

Comment: Ah, oops, thought that was copyFromLocal again for some reason