# Converting HDF5 files into readable/usable data after downloading from HDFS using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hdf5

I am trying to download a dataset of files in the HDF5 format. All the files are located on a HDFS that I set up. I want to use Spark to download the files and then somehow convert them. I havent figured out how to convert the HDF5 files into something usable/readable. Is it possible to convert them into a dataframe and then work on it with pandas?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

I have tried to read some documentation about wrapper classes etc. but I am pretty new to programming and a bit lost.
I worked with csv files before and that worked flawlessly to download them from the HDFS using spark and then running panda commands on the dataframe, but I am struggling with the HDF5 format.

Comment: [h5py](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html#quick) exposes the data as numpy arrays. Going from there to dataframes is trivial. Also, what's wrong with [pandas own support for HDF5](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html)?

Comment: No need to convert HDF5 to pandas dataframes -- just read the HDF5 files as-is. The hardest part is figuring out the schema. Once you know that, it's a snap to access the data. Also, you can use HDFView from The HDF Group to view the data in a GUI.

Comment: @Homer512 the files are located on a HDFS and pandas own mehtods only support local file systems

Comment: @kcw78 thank you for the idea, the HDFView is helpful. I do know what the schema of the dataset looks like. But I am still confused on how to "read the HDF5 files as-is". They are located on a hdfs and I am trying to get them using spark. What would be a command to read them as is?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat speculative since I don't have an HDFS file system to test it.

However, from what I can gather, you can [open HDFS files as file-like objects using Pydoop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335456/17167312)

Using h5py, you can [read HDF5 files from file-like objects](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html) using the `driver="fileobj"` argument. That means, this should work, in theory:

```py
from pydoop import hdfs
import h5py

with hdfs.open('/user/myuser/filename') as f:
    with h5py.File(f, driver='fileobj') as h:
        dataset = h['/group/dataset']
        content = dataset[:]
```

There also seems to be [an HDFS driver for the HDF5 library](https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hadoop-hdfs-hdf5-connector/) but compiling that and getting it to work with h5py or Pandas HDFStore might be challenging.